# Python. Как вытащить подходящие элементы из списка до определённого элемента?

Tags: python, list

Здесь 12 элементов, допустим, я хочу вытащить до 10-го элемента элемент "а". Как этого добиться?

```
list = ['он', 'отпер', 'а', 'дверь', 'своим', 'а', 'ключом', 'и', 'вошел', 'а', 'следом', 'в']
for i in list:
    a = 'а'
    a = list.count(a)
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ['он', 'отпер', 'а', 'дверь', 'своим', 'а', 'ключом', 'и', 'вошел', 'а', 'следом', 'в']
> _0____1____2____3______4____5_____6____7____8____9____10____11
> Десятый элемент  ------------------------------------------->>>>^

Если я вас правильно понял и вам надо напечатать элементы
(`до десятого`, а десятый элемент имеет индекс `9`, т.к. нумерация индексов начинается с ***НУЛЯ***),
значение, которых - `а`.

```
 _list = ['он', 'отпер', 'а', 'дверь', 'своим', 'а', 'ключом', 'и', 'вошел', 'а', 'следом', 'в']

print(*[ i for i in _list[:9] if i == 'а' ], sep='\n')
```

Comment: @Apetry вы удалили свой предыдущий вопрос почему? Разобрались? Если нет, то восстановите его и я постараюсь вам помочь.

Comment: Да, с предыдущим вопросом всё стало ясно. Неточно выразилась: мне нужно не только напечатать элементы, но и посчитать их.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['он', 'отпер', 'а', 'дверь', 'своим', 'а', 'ключом', 'и', 'вошел', 'а', 'следом', 'в']

for number, text in enumerate(list):
    if number == 9:
        break
    else:
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Данилкина выводит все элементы до указанного, правильнее так:

```
my_list = ['он', 'отпер', 'а', 'дверь', 'своим', 'а', 'ключом', 'и', 'вошел', 'а', 'следом', 'в']
result = ", ".join(str(x) for index, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == 'а' and index < 9)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Мне бы хотелось точнее понимать значение в вопросе слова вытащить, но допустим это будет в значении вывести в консоль.*

```
words = ['он', 'отпер', 'а', 'дверь', 'своим', 'а', 'ключом', 'и', 'вошел', 'а', 'следом', 'в']
```

### Срез списка

list()[begin_index : end_index]. Рассматривайте end_index как условие остановки добавления элементов в срез. То есть все элементы начиная с end_index не будут добавлены в срез.

Выводим срез списка words с 0-го по 9-й элемент (индексы).

```
for item in words[ :10 ]:
    print(item)
```

*Аналогичная запись:*

```
print(*words[ :10 ], sep='\n')
```

Звездочкой мы указываем, что элементы среза мы передаем функции print как аргументы. В этом случае стандартно он разделяет их пробелом, но мы указываем разделителем символ перехода на новую строку.

### Счетчик

Определяем внутри цикла, когда нам следует остановить вывод элементов.

*enumerate каждым элементом возвращает кортеж (индекс элемента, элемент).*

```
for item_index, item in enumerate(words):
    if item_index == 10:
        break
    print(item)
```

*Аналогичная запись:*

```
item_index = int()
for item in words:
    if item_index == 10:
        break
    print(item)
    item_index += 1
```

Comment: Для краткости begin_index и end_index можно пропускать в записи.